# Searching for newer Online database server

Tags: android

Since PARSE is going to call off their free services at JANUARY '28 2017 ,It pretty non suggested one to learn it's API's over database and other stuff. Can anyone please suggest me some of the useful Free Online database Servers that are very useful for future along with how to integrate them to my ANDROID Apps.Thanks friends.

Comment: You can look at Simbla. They have an online database, based on Parse.
You can read more about it here: http://www.simbla.com/web_applications.
I think they have the same API as Parse had.
I'm using it for my website where i manage 3 tables where people can make search's and update data.
I found it very easy and useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongo db and interact with the database using node js. 
 The link contains tools that parse is providing to help you move your data  to mongo db.
 [Click on this link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/).